# Iframes v FBML - Why transfer?

Tags: facebook, iframe, fbml, facebook-iframe, facebook-fbml

I have lots of Facebook Fanpages, and I have been told on many occasions to change to iFrames. Facebook developing isn't really my main thing so I havent kept upto date with the change as FBML worked for me.

I have asked a recent question about rotating images and it seems that iFrames will be able to handle this.

Can you tell me what are the good things about iFrames?

Is there an iFrame service without thirdpart branding (i.e WildFire logo at the bottom of page)

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be switching as soon as possible from fbml fan pages to iframe fan page because the FBML pages have been deprecated (you can't create new fbml pages) and it is likely Facebook will start killing FBML page support for existing pages, with little to no notice.

The biggest benefits are almost all javascript code will run now and without making a user first click somewhere.  Laying out pages is a lot cleaner.  And you don't have to learn the fbml tags.  You just make a web page like you normally would and it should run just fine, as long as you understand that iframe code is sandboxed due to cross domain limitations  so you can't try to modify its parent (the Facebook page)

I don't know of any iFrame services, but iFrame pages are so simple - you just host a plain html file or webpage somewhere on a server anywhere and tell Facebook the url for it.  Do note though that the site it is hosted on should have an SSL certificate for users that visit your page with HTTPS enabled on their Facebook account.

Comment: The only real difference is that I can use JavaScript? You can still add Static FMBL to pages I did it yesterday. I have looked at iFrames and they seem the same, I would prefer if they were edited on another page like FBML rather that in the page its self.

Comment: The biggest advantage, bigger than javascript, is that they aren't deprecated.  Staying on deprecated Facebook technology is a slippery slope.